# sh: ip: command not found centos

Tags: php, bash, centos

I am debugging some code and I have the following line that I think is causing errors in my php log `sh: ip: command not found` Any ideas as to why or what packages are missing on the `Centos` server?

**Code:**

`exec("ip tunnel show | cut -f1 -d' ' | cut -f1 -d':'", $someVar);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add path: replace `ip` by `/sbin/ip`.

Comment: Why should we need to specify particularly?

Answer (score 4):

The 'ip' command resides in sbin directory, which may not be in your PATH env variable. There could be more such commands not having their path part of PATH env variable. You need to set /sbin in your path by following below step.

In your shell script, add following two lines BEFORE your exec() line, followed by your exec line:

```
exec("PATH=\$PATH:/sbin ip tunnel show | cut -f1 -d' ' | cut -f1 -d':'", $someVar);
```

Comment: Oh I missed that this was a php code. Thanks for pointing that out! Here is the suggested line then: exec("PATH=\$PATH:/sbin ip tunnel show | cut -f1 -f' ' | cut -f1 -d':'", $someVar)